# Changing value of one item in a collection affects all duplicate items

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I seem to be having an odd issue whereby every time I try to change a value of an item in a collection, it affects all others that contain the same initial values.

An example is below:

```
public class Product : ICloneable
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }

  public Product()
  {
    Id = 0;
    Quantity = 0;
  }

  public Clone()
  {
    return (Product)this.MemberwiseClone();
  }
}

...

private static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(Product product, int quantity)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
  {
    yield return product.Clone();
  }
}

...

IEnumerable<Product> myProducts = Enumerable.Empty<Product>();
Product product1 = new Product() { Id = 0, Name = "Buzz Cola" };
Product product2 = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Choco Bites" };

myProducts = myProducts.Concat(GetProducts(product1, 2));
myProducts = myProducts.Concat(GetProducts(product2, 1));

//Now set the quantity of the first product to be 1.
myProducts.ElementAt(0).Quantity = 1;

foreach(Product product in myProducts)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id: {0}  Quantity: {1}", product.Id, product.Quantity));
}

//Output:
//Id: 0  Quantity: 1
//Id: 0  Quantity: 1 //NO!
//Id: 1  Quantity: 0
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

***Update*** I have updated the question to include the Clone() as suggested. The output is still the same however.

Comment: How are you changing the item?

Comment: myProducts.ElementAt(0).Quantity = 1;

Comment: `myProducts` doesn't have an `Is` or `Quantity` property. Do you mean `product.Id`?

Comment: I've also tried doing a loop, incrementing each quantity by one, and I end up with the Buzz Cola having a quantity of 2!

Comment: I've run your corrected version and it outputs the expected quantities (1, 0, 0)

Comment: @dtb - Ditto, VS2008, .NET Framework 3.5. Dan, is there some important code you're not showing us?

Comment: @Gavin: Yes, I made a mistake in how the actual products are created. I have rewritten the question to reflect this.

Comment: You are adding the same product twice, hence there is only a single instance and changes become visible to both items in the list.

Comment: @Daniel: Is there a better way to do this to prevent the reference from being copied to both objects? I've tried recreating the objects again, and assigning the Id and name to each, but it makes no difference.

Comment: My last comment is a bit weird, but probably everybody got what I wanted to express - there is a single instance and it is added twice, and not there is a single instance because it is added twice.
@Dan better way? You already had working code here - just create and add three products. What are you trying to achieve? A kind of copy-constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a clone method or a copy constructor.

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }

  public Product()
  {
      this.Id = 0;
      this.Name = null;
      this.Quantity = 0;
  }

  public Product(Product product)
  {
      this.Id = product.id;
      this.Name = product.Name;
      this.Quantity = product.Quantity;
  }
}

IList<Product> myProducts = new List<Product>();

Product product1 = new Product() { Id = 0, Name = "Buzz Cola" };
Product product2 = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Choco Bites" };
Product product3 = new Product(product1); // Use copy-constructor.

myProducts.Add(product1);
myProducts.Add(product2);
myProducts.Add(product3);

myProducts[0].Quantity = 1;
```

And now everything should be fine. You can use this together with your cloniung method to produce a large number of clones at once.

Just to note, this code has still a very bad taste - you are creating different product instances with equal ids. I can just guess, but do you want to build something like a shopping cart with cart items having a quantity and a product? If yes, you should really think about splitting the product class into two classes. And think about the accessibility of your properties aganin.

```
public class Product
{
  public Int32 Id { get; private set; }
  public String Name { get; private set; }
}

public class ShoppingCartItem
{
  public Product Product { get; private set; }
  public Int32 Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
  public IList<ShoppingCartItem> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

This solves your current problems because there is no longer a need for cloning products.

Comment: Daniel, I have updated the GetProducts() with     yield return new Product(product); and have created a copy constructor, but the result is still the same. I update one, and both get their quantities changed.

Comment: The problem is the following. When the new quantity is set, the query is evaluated and a new product is created by cloning or calling the copy constructor and the new product is modified. When the collection is printed, the query is reevaluated and the product is cloned or copy-constructed again, hence the update is lost and all quantities are zero. This is a different bug then the original one.

Answer (score 3):

`Product` is a reference type and your `GetProducts` method just yields multiple references to the same `Product` object.

That's why updating one instance updates any others - they're all references to the same object.

Comment: Is there any way to change this reference so that it only relates to one?

Comment: You can either clone the Product object in the GetProducts method, or declare Product as a struct rather than a class

Comment: I have altered GetProducts() so that it does: yield return product.Clone(); and have added the Clone() to Product with return (Product)this.MemberwiseClone(); Alas, the result is still the same.

Comment: I have updated the question with the Clone() changes suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's referencing your first instance with ID=0 twice instead of two separate instances like you expect.

Try changing the ID of the third instance from 0 -> 2 and see if that 'fixes' it.

Comment: Doing this sets the first to 2 as well.

Comment: Then your example in your question doesn't reflect your actual code. Your example works as intended and yields the expected quantities.

Comment: I have redone the code. It didn't reflect the actual code, you are correct. The problem was that I had missed the GetProducts() passing the same object reference twice.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting a few typos in the WriteLine loop (please copy/paste working code) the error fails to reproduce, my output is:

```
Id: 0  Quantity: 1
Id: 1  Quantity: 0
Id: 0  Quantity: 0
```

---

After the changes:

You only create 2 instances, and therefore you are suffering from the very simple fact that you are having 3 references but only 2 instances. And the output is as it should be. It will become a little clearer if you also print the Name property.

But what you apparently want, somewhere in that very complex Enumerator/Concat story is to Clone your products.

Charlie Salts can un-delete his answer, he was right.

Comment: I have rewritten the question, as I have did not reflect the true code.

Comment: @Henk: I have updated the question with the Clone(). The result however, is the same.

Comment: Dan, better first think about what you actually want, Clone() and IClonable are full of traps, certainly for someone who still struggles with value/reference types. Q: Should a clone have the same ID as the original?

Answer (score 1):

both myProducts.ElementAt(0) and myProducts.ElementAt(1) will reference the same object.

Not sure the best way to fix this:
Maybe before you add to a list, check to see if you have a reference to the object already? if you do, [deep clone](http://www.csharp411.com/c-object-clone-wars/) the object and insert it...

Answer (score -1):

Use the indexer instead.

`myProducts[0].Quantity = 1`

Comment: IEnumerable does not provide an indexer.

Comment: I could have sworn he was using a list. Sorry. The code seems to be changing.

Comment: Dan used a list before, but the variable was of type IEnumerable<T> right from the begining, hence you could not access the indexer without a downcast.